# Convert form to service

Tags: c#, windows-services

The thing is I have a form application its a simple program with a filewatcher and an filecopier. But I want to make it into a windows service. Is there any way to run a form in a service (I've read that there was something like this before)?

This is the first service I've tried to make and I can't seem to find a way to get a button in there. Is that even possible?

Summary:

1. Can a form run in a service?
2. Can I have a button in a service?
3. Is it hard to convert a form to a service?

Comment: why do you need a button?  Services are unattended, which doesn't lend itself well to user interface elements

Comment: the button is just for pausing/starting it up again

Comment: you get that by default with services - run services.msc to start/stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service doesn't have an interface so you can't directly run a form *in* a service. You can launch/control services via a form, if that's what you meant. Likewise, you can have a button on the form to control the service but it wouldn't be in the service itself.

Converting a form to a service doesn't make sense due to the UI aspect but converting the logic code to a service is relatively straightforward for simple projects. If you've separated your UI code from the logic, it's pretty straightforward to move that code into a service.

Having said that, depending on what you want to do, you could look into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) as opposed to standard Windows Services.